# How to iterate initialized enumerated types with Delphi 6 and avoid the "out of bounds" error?

Tags: delphi, types, for-loop, loops, enumerate

I am using Delphi 6 Professional.  I am interfacing with a DLL libraty that declares an enumberated type as follows:

```
TExtDllEnum = (ENUM1 = $0, ENUM2 = $1, ENUM3 = $2, ENUM4 = $4, ENUM5 = $8, ENUM6 = $10);
```

As you can see the initialized values are not contiguous.  If I try to iterate the type using a for loop as follows:

```
var
    e: TExtDllEnum;
begin
    for e := Low(TExtToDllEnum) to High(TExtToDllEnum) do
    ... // More code
end;
```

Delphi still increments e by 1 each loop invocation and thereby creates numeric values for e that are not members of the enumerated type (for example, '3'), and resulting in an 'out of bounds' error.  How can I iterate the enumerated type in a for loop that generates only valid values for the enumerated type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By defining a set of constants...

```
type
  TExtDllEnum = (ENUM1 = $0, ENUM2 = $1, ENUM3 = $2, ENUM4 = $4, ENUM5 = $8, ENUM6 = $10);

const
  CExtDllEnumSet = [ENUM1, ENUM2, ENUM3, ENUM4, ENUM5, ENUM6];


var
  e: TExtDllEnum;
begin
  e := Low(TExtDllEnum);
  while e <= High(TExtDllEnum) do
  begin
    if e in CExtDllEnumSet then 
      WriteLn(Ord(e));

    Inc(e);
  end;

  ReadLn;
end.
```

---

and implemented as an iterator - just for fun...

```
type
  TExtDllEnum = (ENUM1 = $0, ENUM2 = $1, ENUM3 = $2, ENUM4 = $4, ENUM5 = $8, ENUM6 = $10);
const
  CExtDllEnumSet = [ENUM1, ENUM2, ENUM3, ENUM4, ENUM5, ENUM6];

type
  TMyIterator = class
  private
    FValue: TExtDllEnum;
  public
    constructor Create;
    function Next: TExtDllEnum;
    function HasNext: Boolean;
  end;

  constructor TMyIterator.Create;
  begin
    FValue := Low(TExtDllEnum);
  end;

  function TMyIterator.HasNext: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := FValue <= High(TExtDllEnum);
  end;

  function TMyIterator.Next: TExtDllEnum;
  begin
    Result := FValue;

    repeat
      Inc(FValue);
    until (FValue in CExtDllEnumSet) or (FValue > High(TExtDllEnum))
  end;

var
  MyIterator: TMyIterator;
begin
  MyIterator := TMyIterator.Create;

  while MyIterator.HasNext do
    WriteLn(Ord(MyIterator.Next));

  MyIterator.Free;

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can remember, there's no way to iterate the way you want.  If the enumeration is not changed frequently, a workaround may be to declare a "index array", which let you iterate the way you want.  The trick is you don't iterate over the enumeration, but over a index which you can in turn "convert" to a valid element in the enum:

I think I can explain the idea better in code:

```
const
  ExtDllEnumElements = 6;
  EnumIndexArray: array[0..ExtDllEnumElements - 1] of TExtDllEnum = (ENUM1, ENUM2, ENUM3, ENUM4, ENUM5, ENUM6);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(EnumIndexArray) to High(EnumIndexArray) do
    WhateverYouWantWith(EnumIndexArray[I]);
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

When you define the enumeration

```
TExtDllEnum = (ENUM1 = $0, ENUM2 = $1, ENUM3 = $2, ENUM4 = $4, ENUM5 = $8, ENUM6 = $10);
```

you actually define the enumeration type consisting of 17 ($10 + 1) possible values.
That is [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Enumerated_Types_with_Explicitly_Assigned_Ordinality).

There are a lot of ways to implement the iteration over assigned enumeration constants only (see the other answers), but the way you are doing it you iterate over 17 values, and that cannot be changed.

Here is one more iteration example that uses the fact that all ENUMx values except ENUM1 are powers of 2:

```
type
  TExtDllEnum = (ENUM1 = $0, ENUM2 = $1, ENUM3 = $2,
                 ENUM4 = $4, ENUM5 = $8, ENUM6 = $10);
var
    e: TExtDllEnum;

begin
  e:= Low(TExtDllEnum);
  repeat
    [..]
    if e = ENUM1 then e:= ENUM2
    else if e = High(TExtDllEnum) then Break
    else e:= e shl 1;
  until False;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't

if the values are binary weighted try using a while loop like this

```
var
    e: TExtDllEnum;
begin
    e := 0;
    While e <= High(TExtToDllEnum) do
    begin
        ... // More code
        e := Power(2, e);
    end;

end;
```